# Tomcat not loading libs

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, tomcat

well my Tomcat (run via Eclipse) seems to fail to load the SQL Server driver lib:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.ktu.gdia.core.MainController.processFile(MainController.java:132)
    at org.ktu.gdia.core.MainController.run(MainController.java:57)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://isd.ktu.lt:1433;DatabaseName=LN2012_bakDB2
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDriver.connect(PoolingDriver.java:180)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.ktu.gdia.database.DbActions.openConn(DbActions.java:64)
    at org.ktu.gdia.core.MainController.processFile(MainController.java:134)
    at org.ktu.gdia.core.MainController.run(MainController.java:57)
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.ktu.gdia.database.GenForestDatabase.personExists(GenForestDatabase.java:178)
    at org.ktu.gdia.core.MainController.processFile(MainController.java:158)
    at org.ktu.gdia.core.MainController.run(MainController.java:57)
```

the sqljdbc.jar and sqljdb4.jar and jtds-1.3.0.jar are in the Tomcat/lib directory. I'm using Tomcat 7. Is it possible, that Eclipse makes Tomcat use a different lib directory then the one in the Tomcat 7 which it is supposed to use?

Comment: Try running tomcat from the command line, if your libs are loaded then it seems likely that eclipse is running a different tomcat (or perhaps running in a different location).

Comment: It's most likely that Eclipse is using a different Tomcat "base"(`CATALINA_BASE`)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all of those JARs, just the one that you actually want to load.  It appears to the Microsoft driver, not jTDS.

I don't know what Eclipse is doing, but Tomcat expects JDBC driver JARs to be loaded from its /lib directory.

I don't agree that the problem is failing to load the driver.  "No suitable driver" usually means that the URL syntax in the connection string is incorrect.

You have

```
jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://isd.ktu.lt:1433;DatabaseName=LN2012_bakDB2
```

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx) URL suggests the following format:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;databaseName=dbNameHere;integratedSecurity=true;
```

If the URL appears to be right, I'd start checking other things:

1. Can you ping server `isd.ktu.lt` from the server where you run your Java app?  If you can't see that server Java won't, either.
2. Can you successfully connect to that server using Microsoft SQL Server Studio?  If it can't Java won't, either.
3. Are you certain that the SQL Server listener is configured to listen on port 1433, the default?  Lots of DBAs choose something other than the default for security reasons.
4. Looks like you're using a database connection pool, as you should.  Check to see that your [JNDI configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) is correct.

Here's configuration from an app that successfully connects to SQL Server:

```
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=db"/>
```

Comment: Well I think I've tried that before, but I tried it again, left only sqljdbc4.jar and changed the url, I think I got the same error, just for the different url: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://isd.ktu.lt:1433;DatabaseName=LN2012_bakDB2;integratedSecurity=true;
I don't notice any other difference?

Comment: "databaseName" instead of "DatabaseName".  Maybe case matters.

Comment: Hmm, seems to be the same:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://isd.ktu.lt:1433;databaseName=LN2012_bakDB2;integratedSecurity=true;
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

Comment: Try leaving off the integratedSecurity flag & pass in the username and password for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL must be `jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;DatabaseName=yourDbName` 
and Class name must be like `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`. You can download and use the MicrosoftSQL Server JDBC Driver 2.0 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2505)

Comment: Hmm, I changed the URL, but I seem to be getting the same error:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://isd.ktu.lt:1433;databaseName=LN2012_bakDB2;integratedSecurity=true;
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
What exactly do you mean by  Class name must be like com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver  ? I'm using Database connection pooling.

Comment: Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

Comment: As you are using database connection pooling your context.xml should have an entry like  driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"